# How to fix starting position of view to drag

Tags: android, android-layout

When I hold down on my `ImageView` to drag it across the screen, the `ImageView` becomes invisible, and the draggable version of the `ImageView` will spawn onto the screen with the center of the spawned view underneath my fingertip; this is not organic. I want the draggable version of the view to spawn directly on top of the `ImageView`, and not directly underneath my finger tip.

For example, If my `ImageView` is a Ace of Diamonds on top of a card deck, and I want to drag the card off the deck, the card should drag smoothly off the deck, and not reposition itself underneath my finger and then drag, if that makes sense.

This my code for the draggable ImageView; I'm not sure how to make the dragging animation smoother as described above.

```
public class DragView2 extends AppCompatImageView
implements View.OnDragListener, View.OnTouchListener{

    private static final String TAG = DragView2.class.getSimpleName();

    public DragView2(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, null);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        this.setOnDragListener(this);
    }

    public DragView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        this.setOnDragListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) 
    {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction())
        {
            case ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN");
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event)
    {
        final View viewToDrag = (View) event.getLocalState();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                Log.d(TAG,"ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                Log.d(TAG,"ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                Log.d(TAG,"ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                Log.d(TAG,"ACTION_DROP");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                Log.d(TAG,"ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
                view.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        viewToDrag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG,"default");
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A pointer towards the solution.

I extended the **View** class. Use the following code to successfully drag the object at the right coords.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    float oldX, oldY, newX, newY, originalX, originalY;

    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            oldX = event.getX();
            oldY = event.getY();
            originalX = oldX;
            originalY = oldY;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            newX = event.getX();
            newY = event.getY();
            updatePositions(oldX, oldY, newX, newY);
            oldX = newX;
            oldY = newY;
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            newX = event.getX();
            newY = event.getY();

           //  USE ANY OF THE FOLLOWING
           //  updatePositions(oldX, oldY, newX, newY);
           //  updatePositions(originalX, originalY, newX, newY);


            oldX = newX;
            oldY = newY;
    }
}

private void updatePositions(float pt1, float pt2, float pt3, float pt4) {

  // code to change the position of the position

}
```

Make the 6 variables class variables and use Toast to show positions. Hope this hints at solution :)